# How to pass in a read bash variable in linux and sent it as a message in git commit?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I would like to automate the git commit function and be able to read in a message like as follows in bash:

```
echo -n "Enter message and press [ENTER]: " 
read mess

cd /my/dir
git add *
git commit -m "$(mess)"
```

However, it tells me in bash that in `line 6: mess: command not found.` Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script, `$(mess)` denotes a sub-shell which executes the command `mess`; which isn't a real command.

Replace the parenthesis with brackets.

```sh
echo -n "Enter message and press [ENTER]: " 
read mess

cd /my/dir
git add *
git commit -m "${mess}"
```

**Update**

Per the [bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), under command substitution it states the following,

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. There are two forms:
>       $(command) 
>   or
>       `command` 
>   Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

Comment: thanks, this might be elementary, but what is a subshell?

Comment: I have added the definition to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I topvoted your answer, much appreciate it!